# Insert elements by javascript without losing jquery mobile style page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create dynamically through data received from a data base a group of checkboxes. I'm creating the checkboxes using JavaScript. But When I put them in my page, they appears without jquery mobile theme.

In javascript I'm writing the whole tag (like

```
"<input class='name' data-theme='a' type='checkbox' data-iconpos='right' style='text-align:left' '><label for='checkbox2'>"+ sessionStorage.name + "</label>";
```

`sessionStorage.name` has data that I received from database.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to refresh them.

```
checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Check [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/forms/checkboxes/methods.html) for more

**UPDATE**

The above is for version 1.2.1. The latest version has a more general way of dealing with this situation. Check [here](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/faq/injected-content-is-not-enhanced.html)

> jQuery Mobile has no way to know when you have injected content into a
>   page. To let jQuery Mobile know you have injected content that must be
>   enhanced, you need to either make sure the plugins are called to
>   enhance the new elements or trigger("create") on the parent container
>   so you don't have to call each plugin manually.
>
> Create vs. refresh: An important distinction
>
> Note that there is an important difference between the create event
>   and refresh method that some widgets have. The create event is suited
>   for enhancing raw markup that contains one or more widgets. The
>   refresh method should be used on existing (already enhanced) widgets
>   that have been manipulated programmatically and need the UI be updated
>   to match.

**UPDATE 2**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.js"></script>

<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="chamada_item">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-0 ">Static
    </label>
  </form>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('<label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-0 ">Dynamic with trigger create</label>').appendTo("#chamada_item").trigger("create");
        $('<label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-0 ">Dynamic without trigger</label>').appendTo("#chamada_item");
    });
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is not working out. 
I added the .trigger('create'), but it still are not being enhanced.

 $("<input class='.class' data-theme='a' type='checkbox' data-iconpos='right' style='text-align:left' '>").appendTo("#chamada_item").trigger("create");

Am I writting correctly?

Comment: $('<input class=".class" data-theme="a" type="checkbox" data-iconpos="right" style="text-align:left">').appendTo("#chamada_item").trigger("create");

Comment: Check my update. The dynamic with trigger has the style, but the one without the trigger does not. Just copy and paste it in a html file.